# refering to field out of subeselects scope

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm working on a piece of SQL at the moment and i need to retrieve every row of a dataset with a median and an average aggregated in it.

Example

i have the following set

`ID;month;value`

and i would like to retrieve something like :

`ID;month;value;average for this month;median for this month`

without having to group by my result.

So it would be something like :

```
SELECT ID,month,value,
(SELECT AVG(value) FROM myTable) as "myAVG" 
FROM myTable
```

but i would need that average to be the average for that month specifically. So, rows where the month="January" will have the average and median for "January" etc ...

Issue here is that i did not find a way to refer to the value of month in my subquery

`(SELECT AVG(value) FROM myTable)`

Does someone have a clue?

P.S: It's a redshift database i'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select all rows from the table, and do a left join with a select statement that does group by month. This way, you would get every row, and the group by results with them for that month.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable a 
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT Month, Sum(value being summed) as mySum
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Month
) b 
ON a.Month = b.Month
```

Helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
with myavg as
(SELECT month, AVG(value) as avgval FROM myTable group by month) 
, mymed as
(select month, median(value) as medval from myTable group by month)
select ID, month, value, ma.avgval, mm.medval 
from mytable m left join myavg ma 
on m.month = ma.month
left join mymed mm 
on m.month = mm.month
```

You can use a `cte` to do this. However, you need a `group by` on month, as you are calculating an aggregate value.

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift you can use [Window Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_AVG.html).

```
select month,
avg(value) over
(PARTITION BY month rows unbounded preceding) as avg
from myTable
order by 1;
```